# How to handle updates of a web application in with multi tenant databases?

Tags: c#, azure, multi-tenant

I am about to develop a new SaaS solution where i want to use single web application (SPA), with multi tenant databases which share the same schema. However i have a concerns regards update and deployment routines.

[image]

Lets assume i made a change in web application and database where i added a new column to some table. Now i want to update Web application and at the same time i want to update all the databases with new column without application going down for maintenance. I can start by updating a single tenant database, but as soon as changes to tenant are made, web app is not current anymore for the tenant. Other way around i can update Web application first, but then application is not current for any tenants anymore.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Your web app shouldn't know the structure of the database. It should know about a server API. And you can version that to allow different versions of the web app to co-exist.

Comment: you could always provision a new instance of the web app for each tenant. Then the environments for each customer are truly isolated and you can update each in turn. If you've got separate databases for each then you're kind of going down that route already really. Or you could version your API as suggested, and set a flag for each customer which says which API version they use, and let the web app take that value and adjust the URLs it calls accordingly. You have to ensure your API changes are backwards-compatible though really. If you want to make breaking changes you might need downtime.

Comment: @HansKilian can you iterate please? How would you implement that?

Comment: There are different ways to do it. This is a good starting point: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of system architecture, and the answer heavily depends on your requirements and constraints.

As for the client, I agree with @HansKilian, it shouldn't be coupled to DB schema.

As for the server updates, you may want to run your app in Docker. So that each [instances of] Docker container is dedicated to a specific tenant, and as such, it works against a specific database. That is, no two tenants share the same container. This is beneficial for many different reasons. For example:

- Information security: one of SaaS concerns is data of one tenant accidentally leaking to another. If you never run two tenants in the same container, you reduce the chance of such thing happening.
- Fine-grained deployment: when you update a specific tenant's DB, you take down only containers related to this specific tenant. The rest of the tenants continue to run.

In order to implement such an architecture, you need routing of incoming requests to correct containers. This can be achieved in many different ways. For example, you may put NGINX in front of your web app, make each request contain a header that identifies a tenant, and define routing rules based on that. Or you may use Docker in swarm mode and include tenant ID in container service name.

This was just an example of what can be done, not sure how well it fits your scenario -- it all depends.